# jQuery for the dropdown change event does not populate textarea

Tags: jquery, ajax, tinymce

I would like to ask if anyonce can help me.

I have form with a drop down list. my problem is that I am using TinyMCE as editor.

When I select an item in the drop down it doesn't populate the TinyMCE textarea but another textarea is open by jQuery.

Here's my code, can anyone help me to fix so that the results of the drop down will show on the TinyMCE editor.

Thanks a lot.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script><br />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#select').change(function () {
                    var option = $(this).val();
                    $.get('select.php', {select: option}, function (data) {
                        $('#result').html(data).hide().fadeIn(1);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            tinyMCE.init({mode: "textareas", editor_selector: "mceEditor"});

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('form').submit(function ()
                {

                    alert(tinyMCE.get('result').getContent());

                });
            });

        </script>

    </head>

    <select name="select" id="select">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
    </select>

    <form id="ajax-form" class="autosubmit" method="POST" action="">
        <textarea class="mceEditor" id="result" name="notes"/></textarea>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Here's my PHP that get the data:

```
<?php

if($_GET['select'] == 'option1') {
    echo 'the option you have chosen is 1';
} elseif($_GET['select'] == 'option2') {
    echo 'the option you have chosen is 2';
} elseif($_GET['select'] == 'option3') {
    echo 'the option you have chosen is 3';
} elseif($_GET['select'] == 'option4') {
    echo 'the option you have chosen is 4';
} elseif($_GET['select'] == 'option5') {
    echo 'the option you have chosen is 5';
}

?>
```

Comment: Use tinyMCE's `setContent` function. `tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(your_content);`.

Comment: @Shahid can you help me to edit my code or sample thanks.

Comment: Instead of `select.php` in `$.get` write full URL of your php file. Use `{'select':option}` instead of `{select:option}`. I do not know the purpose of `$('#result').html(data).hide().fadeIn(1);` but there you can use `tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(your_content);`.

Comment: @shahid, your suggestion works to but I cannot give you credit because you gave the answer as comments. sorry but your suggestion works great. thanks pal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$('#result').html(data).hide().fadeIn(1);` (why do you call hide here?)

use

```
tinymce.get('result').setContent(data);
```